# why isn't this code working? Get count from generate date range

Tags: mysql, date

I have two pieces of tables, one is a table of the visit and the only room table lists the type of rooms and the number of rooms.

I would like to know the availability of rooms on 2015-11-11 until 2015-11-12, so I made a range of data and try to script like this:

1. I made a date range:
2. then I searched for information  from a table visit how many unused rooms on each type of suite room table

this my code to get data with date range between 2015-11-11 and 2015-11-12:

```
select a.Date, b.id_room, (b.num-count(c.datex)) as remain
from (
select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) - (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a cross join rooms b  join visit c on c.datex where a.Date between '2015-11-11' and '2015-11-12' group by b.id_room,a.Date
```

This my table source

```
visit table
+----+------------+-------+----------+
| no | datex      | room  | guest_id |
+----+------------+-------+----------+
|  1 | 2015-11-12 | 10    |      200 |
|  5 | 2015-11-13 | 10    |      200 |
|  6 | 2015-11-14 | 10    |      200 |
|  7 | 2015-11-13 | 20    |      201 |
|  8 | 2015-11-16 | 20    |      300 |
|  9 | 2015-11-16 | 20    |      305 |
+----+------------+-------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

rooms
+---------+----------+-----+
| id_room | name     | num |
+---------+----------+-----+
|      10 | Standart |   2 |
|      20 | VIP      |   4 |
+---------+----------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I expected results are as follows like this:

```
+----------+----------+--------+
|   date   | id_room  | remain |
+----------+----------+--------+
|2015-11-11|    10    |   2    |
|2015-11-11|    20    |   4    |
|2015-11-12|    10    |   1    |
|2015-11-12|    20    |   4    |
+----------+----------+--------+
```

but from the execution of the script above results are not as expected. This my result

```
+----------+----------+-------+
|   date   | id_room  |remain |
+----------+----------+-------+
|2015-11-11|    10    | -4    |
|2015-11-12|    10    | -4    |
|2015-11-11|    20    | -2    |
|2015-11-12|    20    | -2    |
+----------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Your query is scary. What if you get a new room? You must rewrite all your queries. That can't be a solution. Can you please give a better example what you want to do? From your example it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.Date,a.dop as id_room ,avail-ifnull(used.top,0) as remain
from (
select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) - (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date, id_room as dop, num as avail
from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
cross join (select id_room,num from rooms group by id_room) as e

) a left join (select datex,room,count(datex) as top from visit group by datex, room) as used on used.datex=a.Date where a.Date between '2015-11-11' and '2015-11-12' group by a.Date,a.dop;
```